# Is there any Common Name for Edit,Save,Delete,Select

Tags: c#, design, class

Can anyone suggest me a Common Name for Edit,Save,Delete,Select

I want to create a Interface in C#, which will support all these methods.

My Context is :

I am developing an Invoice Application in which i need a Product to be Created,Deleted,Updated,Selected

Comment: Document / DocumentActions

Comment: How come document

Comment: document is the thing intended for edit, save, delete

Comment: What context are these operations in? Documents, files, objects...?

Comment: want you display that text in menu? and on that text's click event you want to do that operation? right?

Comment: Can you give us the a bit more information on the context? I also thought about documents, which is apparently not the context you think about.

Comment: Edit, Save, and Delete are all the common names for themselves...

Comment: @ThomasEding: I think the question is about a general name which includes both Edit, Save and Delete, not three separate "common names" for each.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) is usually the technical term that is used to describe create/read/update/delete functionality.

> ...**create, read, update and delete (CRUD)** (Sometimes called SCRUD with an "S" for Search) are the four basic functions of [persistent storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_storage). Sometimes *CRUD* is expanded with the words *retrieve* instead of *read*, *modify* instead of *update*, or *destroy* instead of delete. It is also sometimes used to describe [user interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_interface) conventions that facilitate viewing, searching, and changing information; often using computer-based forms and reports... The acronym may be extended to CRUDL to cover *listing* of large data sets which bring additional complexity such as [pagination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination) when the data sets are too large to hold easily in memory.
>
> Another variation of CRUD is BREAD, an acronym for "Browse, Read, Edit, Add, Delete"...

Comment: Good example of a good answer salvaging an at-face-value bad question :)

Comment: Actually it's Create Read Update Delete :)

Comment: Honestly, this answer seems for me only like a wild guessing around what the OP could have meant. And I personally dislike wild guessing (though I don't downvote the answer, since it is not plain wrong). I only wonder why such an answer gets so many upvotes.

Comment: @DocBrown - the answer is upvoted because it's a *brilliant* guess at an answer to a vague question.   It might not be the answer the original asker intended to get, but it's the perfect answer to the question as asked.

Comment: what if, there is also Select method

Comment: CRUD just seemed obvious and it has the connotation of doing the dirty work.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO there is no really good common name for those operations. Besides the suggestions of the commenters to give your interface a name related to the kind of objects you want to use it for in your context, you could call the interface something like `IEditableSaveableDeleteable` or `IEditableSaveable` (the latter assumes when something is saveable that it should be clear in your context that it must also be deleteable).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not given a context of edit, save and delete, I will use the term *OBJECT* which you would eventually replace to suit your context.

Next, edit, save and delete are each some kind of change. So, it makes your interface to begin with the word Modify.

The third parameter which will be useful in a name is the subject. "Who is changing it?" I will use the term *SUBJECT* in the name which you would need to replace suitably.

All combined here is my suggestion:

> IModify*OBJECT*By*SUBJECT*

Ex. `IModifyFileBySuperuser` or `IModifyUserByAdmin`

Hope this helps.